# ¿como uso un string en un struct para decidir que dato mostrar?

Tags: c++

buenas. mi pregunta consiste en saber como usar el **string muestra** para decidir que parte de **cuerpo** mostrar. ej: si ingreso "nombre" me muestre su nombre.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct vector2d{
    double x,y;
};

struct cuerpo{
    string nombre;
    double masa;
    vector2d pocicion,aceleracion,velocidad;
};

int main(){       //nombre, masa, pocicion,aceleracion,velocidad
    cuerpo test = {"andres",25.25,{2.3,5.2},{1.2,5.4},{5.4,9.5}};
    string muestra;

    cout<<"que desea mostrar? : ";
    cin>>muestra;//masa
    cout<<test.cuerpo.muestra;//deberia de aparecer masa (25.25) Y SI,
                              //ya se que esa es una manera INCORRECTA de hacerlo,
                              //pero no se cual es la manera correcta.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma sería dejando la selección de lo que debe mostrarse a cargo de la clase cuerpo; por ejemplo, con una función miembro que devuelva una string para mostrar con cout.

```
string cuerpo::mostrar(const string& muestra)
{
    if(muestra == "nombre")
        return nombre;
    else if(muestra == "masa")
        return to_string(masa);
    // else if(etcétera...)
    return "";
}
```